# Xamarin Forms: ContentPages in TabbedPage

Tags: c#, xaml, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to put some custom Content Pages into a Tabbed Page. Sadly I am not sure, how to do this with the XAML syntax. My dummy project looks like the following:

Page 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Page1">
<Label Text="Page 1" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</ContentPage>
```

Page 2 exactly the same. The Tabbed Page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Navigation">
    <ContentPage x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Page1" Title="Home">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Page2" Title="Browse">
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

The Pages just won't show up? How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are doing it wrong.
You must place the pages as the TabbedPage Children.

Here is the solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:mypages="clr-namespace:MyApp.Pages;assembly=MyApp"
            x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Navigation">
  <TabbedPage.Children>
    <mypages:Page1 Title="Home"/>
    <mypages:Page2 Title="Browse"/>
  </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

In alternative you can do it programmatically:

```
public class TabsPage : TabbedPage
{
    public TabsPage ()
    {
        this.Children.Add (new Page1 () { Title = "Home" });
        this.Children.Add (new Page2 () { Title = "Browse" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As on date today, it's not necessary to add "Children" property. If your Pages are in another directory say "PagesDirectory". You can reference the content page "Page1" as below, it will work absolutely fine:

```
 <TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:YourApp.Views.PagesDirectory"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="YourApp.Views.TabbedPage"
        Title="Tabbed Page">
```

```
<views:Page1 Title="Content Page 1"></views:Page1>
<views:Page2 Title="Content Page 2"></views:Page2>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Children property on the TabbedPage

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MyApp.Pages.Navigation">
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <ContentPage Title="Home">
    </ContentPage>
    <ContentPage Title="Browse">
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Attribute Class from the XAML namespace is only accessible on the root element.!

Comment: The other answer is more detailed but the solution is the same, OP his mistake was not to use the correct tag for the children. What I correctly added in my example!! Thx for the downvote djeezes

Comment: The other answer and mine were added at the same time by the way. So is not like I added mine later to make a point or something

Comment: I am not saying you were making a point, but OP wants to link it to already created page, unless its been specified in code behind or by class property its useless. Your new answer just creates dummy Content Pages but wont link to his already created `Page1` and `Page2` Hence the down-vote. I had the same case FYI

Comment: This works! No idea why it was downloaded, but this is the cleanest way to do it imho!